# Yeoman Javascript error involving 'mkdir'

Tags: javascript, npm, generator, yeoman, meanjs

I'm setting up a Meanjs instance with a Yeoman generator. When I do 'sudo yo meanjs' everything works fine until it looks like it is trying to make a directory and it fails, any ideas on what is going on here?

```
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node: Finished

> bson@0.2.5 install /Users/xxx/Documents/mean/node_modules/connect-
  mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bson.node: Finished
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/xxx/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.15'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/xxx/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.15']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/xxx/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.15',
npm ERR!   parent: 'grunt-contrib-uglify' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/xxx/Documents/mean
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/xxx/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.15
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/xxx/.npm/uglify-js/2.4.15'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a pretty common error.

Yeoman is running the following:

```
bower install & npm install
```

Bower install succeeded, however NPM install is failing because of user permissions. Just run:

```
sudo npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

The ZenCoder's answer is spot on, but if you want to permanently fix this permissions error, you can follow the tutorial at: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Since you're on a Mac, you could actually avoid npm permissions errors altogether by just installing node instead via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

`brew install node` (this will install npm too)

[Homebrew installs programs to a directory that doesn't require `sudo` for write](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-), so you can `npm install -g <whatever>` freely without it.

Comment: Good complementary answer!